# Is it possible to set max image size by parent max?

Tags: html, css

I have simple code like this:

**CSS:**

```
.timeline-header {
    max-width: 508px;
    max-height: 159px;
/*  width: 508px;
    height: 159px;*/
}

.timeline-header img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="timeline-header">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Big_Sur_June_2008.jpg">
</div>
```

Is it possible to somehow to set image size by it's parents `max-*` sizes? By default it works by default sizes...

Comment: i don't think u can u have to set the `img` max-size

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mgleeson/t8ZGC/

Comment: Do you want to scale but maintain the aspect ratio of the image or do you just stretch the image to fill the box?

Comment: Check my JSFiddle out if you're curious about why my solution works.

Answer (score 1):

css inherit is what you're looking for.

```
.timeline-header, {
    max-width: 508px;
    max-height: 159px;
/*  width: 508px;
    height: 159px;*/
}
.timeline-header img{
    max-width: inherit;
    max-height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="timeline-header">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Big_Sur_June_2008.jpg">
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mgleeson/t8ZGC/)

Comment: @NoNameZ try my solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

Just set the `max-`sizes to `inherit`.

By doing this, the `img`will inherit the size of it's parent.

```
.timeline-header {
    max-width: 508px;
    max-height: 159px;
/*  width: 508px;
    height: 159px;*/
}

.timeline-header img {
    max-width: inherit;
    max-height: inherit;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4Vx3/1/)